# How to check if Axios response data is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

How to check if axios response is empty. Sometimes my response. data will be [ ]. Currently, it aways alerts "data there" is there a better way to do this than response.data.length >= 1

```
return await axios
    .get(url.rest_api + '/team_members', {
      params: {
        primaryOwner: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
        teamMemberEmail: emailText,
      },
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data) {
        alert('data there');
      } else {
        alert('nothing here');
      }
      return response.data;
    })
```

Comment: "is there a better way to do this than response.data.lenght >= 1" Nope. You can do `if (response.data.lenght)`, it's a bit shorter but the same

Comment: It dependes on the endpoint response

Answer (score 0):

you can check the availability with:
`const isDataAvailable = response.data && response.data.length;`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Response Schema](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema), `response.data` is an instance of an `Object` (please correct me if I'm wrong).
So we can check if data is not an `empty string` AND if it's constructor is and instance of an `Object`.

That's how I check it

```
if (response.data !== '' && response.data.constructor === Object) {
   //do something
}
```

Never fails (for me at least)